# Access to a Java static inner class with Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, inner-classes

I'm trying access to a static inner class method, but I can't find the right way.

I need to write this java code in Clojure:

```
SessionProperties sessionProperties = SessionProperties.Builder().mediaMode(MediaMode.ROUTED).build();
```

My code is:

```
(:import [com.opentok OpenTok MediaMode SessionProperties SessionProperties$Builder]))

(def sessionProperties (.build (.mediaMode SessionProperties$Builder MediaMode/ROUTED))
```

And this is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: mediaMode for class java.lang.Class
```

I'm using the [opentok Java library](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK/blob/master/src/main/java/com/opentok/SessionProperties.java) and I don't understand how to access to mediaMode method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Java code does not work. To fix the remedy, add the `new` keyword between `=` and `SessionProperties.Builder()`. It should be:

```
SessionProperties sessionProperties = new SessionProperties.Builder()
  .mediaMode(MediaMode.ROUTED)
  .build();
```

You can do this in Clojure as follows.

```
user> (import '(com.opentok SessionProperties$Builder MediaMode))
com.opentok.MediaMode

user> (def session-properties (.. (SessionProperties$Builder.)
                                  (mediaMode MediaMode/ROUTED)
                                  build))
#'user/session-properties

user> session-properties
#<SessionProperties com.opentok.SessionProperties@54fc58ee>
```