# Initialise google-maps-services-java GeoApiContext in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I want to be able to make a context in clojure for the google maps java services, https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

In their documentation they show that the java command to create a context is this...

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("AIza...").build();
```

How can this be turned into a clojure def?

(I think I am stumbling over "Builder", as using clojure/reflect I can't see any mention of it.  My java experience is minimal.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to a Java static inner class with Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102547/access-to-a-java-static-inner-class-with-clojure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $ to get to a static inner class:

```
(-> (com.google.maps.GeoApiContext$Builder.) (.apiKey "blah") .build)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!